# Periods and $\mathscr{P}(w)$ of the elliptic curve $y^2=4(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$

Tags: elliptic-curves, periodic-functions, elliptic-integrals

I changed the curve to Weierstrass form as suggested: $y^2=4(x+1)x(x-1)$ We have $e_1=-1$, $e_2=0$, $e_3=1$ and $e_1<e_2<e_3$. Firstly, I will find the half periods $w_1,w_2,w_3$.

$\begin{array}. w_3=\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{4(x+1)x(x-1)}}dx\overset{x=1+\tan^2\theta}=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2-sin^2\theta}}d\theta=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}K(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}).\end{array}$

$\begin{array}.w_2=w_3+\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{4(x+1)x(x-1)}}dx\overset{x=\tan^2\theta}=w_3+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\pm i}{\sqrt{1-2sin^2\theta}}d\theta=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}K(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})\pm i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}K(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}).\end{array}$

$\begin{array}.w_1=w_2+\int_{-1}^0\frac{1}{\sqrt{4(x+1)x(x-1)}}dx\overset{x=-1+\tan^2\theta}=w_2+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-2\cos^2\theta)(1-3\cos^2\theta)}}d\theta=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}K(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})\pm i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}K(\frac{1}{2})\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}K(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}).\end{array}$

So, $w_3=\frac{1}{{\sqrt{2}}}K(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$ and $w_1=i\frac{1}{{\sqrt{2}}}K(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$.

Also, its associated Weierstrass $\mathscr{P}$-function is:
$$\mathscr{P}(w)=e_3+\frac{e_1-e_3}{sn^2(\sqrt{e_1-e_3}w)}=3-\frac{2}{sn^2(i\sqrt{2}w)}$$
where $k=\frac{\sqrt{e_2-e_3}}{\sqrt{e_1-e_3}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

My questions:

1. Are my computations correct? I am confused about the standart formulas/definitions. I just took them from a book. Especially those $\pm$s confused me.
2. I don't know much about the Weierstrass's $\mathscr{P}$-function. What is the use of it for the elliptic curve?
3. Solve $\mathscr{P}(w)=0$.

Thanks for any helpfull comments.

Comment: Your elliptic curve is $y^2=4(x^3-x)$ it has CM by $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ so the periods are $a,ia,(1+i)a$ where $a$ has a closed form in term of $B(1/2,1/4)$ whence $\Gamma(1/4)$. The Weierstrass function is the inverse of $\int \frac{dx}{4(x^3-x)}$, it is meromorphic on a complex torus.

Comment: $\Gamma(\frac{1}{4})$ is too big. Are you serious? @reuns

Comment: ??? $a$ has a closed-form in term of $\Gamma(1/4)$ of course I'm serious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are a bit confused and almost correct. Your question
is about the elliptic curve $$ y^2=4(x-1)(x-2)(x-3). $$
Note that this is not in the standard Weierstrass form
because the coefficient of $\;x^2\;$ is not zero. Thus,
let $\;x = X+2\;$ and now the equation is
$$ y^2=4(X+1)X(X-1)=4X^3-4X=4X^3 -g_2X-g_3 . $$
where $\;g_2 = 4,\; g_3 = 0.\;$ Now the roots of
the cubic are $$e_1=1,\quad e_2=-1,\quad e_3=0.$$
The corresponding real half period $\; w_1 \approx 1.3110\;$
and the imaginary half period
$$ w_2=iw_1 \quad \text{ while }\quad
w_3 = -w_1-w_2 = -(1+i)w_1.$$
Verify that $$
\wp(w_1) = \wp(-w_1) = e_1,\;
 \wp(w_2) = \wp(-w_2) = e_2,\;
 \wp(w_3) = \wp(-w_3) = e_3. $$

You wrote:

> I am confused about the standard formulas/definitions.
> I just took them from a book.

but did not mention which book. I recommend the
[DLMF Chapter 23](https://dlmf.nist.gov/23) about
Weierstrass elliptic functions. It specifically
mentions the different conventions about notations
for these elliptic functions which can be confusing.

To make the connection of your elliptic curve to Weierstrass
functions, let $\;x(z) = \wp(z)+2,\; y(z) = \wp'(z).\;$ Then
verify that $\; y(w_1) = y(w_2) = y(w_3) = 0\;$ and that
$\; x(w_1) = 3,\; x(w_2) = 1,\; x(w_3) = 2.\;$

I used the Mathematica code

```
g23 = {N[4, 20], 0};
{w1, w2} = WeierstrassHalfPeriods[g23];

wp[z_, g23_:g23] := WeierstrassP[z, g23];
wpp[z_, g23_:g23] := WeierstrassPPrime[z, g23];
x[z_] := wp[z] + 2;
y[z_] := wpp[z];
xy[z_] := {x[z], y[z]};
chop[v_] := Rationalize[v, 10^20];

w3 = -w1-w2; (* or w3 = w1+w2 *)
vw = {w1, w2, w3};
ve = wp[vw];
vxy = xy /@ vw;

Print["e1..e3 = ", chop[ve]];
Print["xy1..e3 = ", chop[vxy]];
(*
e1..e3 = {1, -1, 0}
xy1..e3 = {{3, 0}, {0, 0}, {2, 0}}
*)
```

and you can use the code yourself in the
[Wolfram Cloud](https://www.wolframcloud.com/).

Alternatively, you can use this
[PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr//gp.html) code
in your browser.

```
[g2, g3] = [4, 0];
E = ellinit(-[g2, g3]/4);
[w1, w2] = ellperiods(E)/2;
w3 = -w1-w2; /* orw3 =  w1+w2 */
vw = [w1, w2, w3];
ve = [ellwp(E, z) | z <- vw];
vxy = [xy(z) | z <- vw];
xy(z) = ellwp(E, z, 1) + [2, 0];
chop(v) = [bestappr(z, 10^20) | z <- v];

print("e1..3 = ", chop(ve));
print("xy(w1..3) = ", chop(vxy))
/* 
e1..3 = [1, -1, 0]
xy(w1..3) = [[3, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0]]
 */
```

Comment: @TymaGaidash Where did you get $\;\wp(1)=w_1\,$ (which is false)? It is $\;\wp(w_1)=1.$

Comment: $\wp(e_1)=w_1$ and $e_1=1$, so $\wp(1)=w_1$. It comes from after “the roots of the cubic are” and after “Verify that”. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @TymaGaidash Oops! Thanks for that comment! I will fix it.